# How do i proceed to install mariadb as drop in replacement for mysql on a zend server 6 environnment?

Tags: mysql, zend-server, mariadb

the company i work for is considering for multiple reasons (some of them libked to the politics of open source and oracle) a switch from MySQL to Mariadb. Our development team has been using Zend Server (now it's 6th version) which always install mysql. Is it possible to switch from mySQl to Mariadb smoothly? are there any hurdles that we should be aware of ahead of time? The OS for every development computer is Ubuntu 13.04 at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there should be no more issues than when upgrading to a new MySQL version.

See [How can I upgrade from MySQL to MariaDB?](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/how-can-i-upgrade-from-mysql-to-mariadb/)

Comment: we proceeded to  replace Mysql by Mariadb and there were actually no issues at all (so far...). Thank you